# Retain custom titlebar color when not in focus

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I have a UWP app with custom titlebar background & foreground color. It works great except when the app is not in focus it will turn the titlebar back to the original white color.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
        titleBar.BackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Black;
        titleBar.ForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.White;
        titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Black;
        titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.White;     
    }
```

How do I retain the custom titlebar color even when the app is not in focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *Inactive* colors for this purpose.

```
titleBar.InactiveBackgroundColor = titleBar.BackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Black;
titleBar.InactiveForegroundColor = titleBar.ForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.White;
titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Black;
titleBar.ButtonInactiveForegroundColor = titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.White;
```

The **Buttons** have *Hover* and *Pressed* color sets too.

[image]

Comment: Note that for usability, it is still recommended that you use different colors for active and inactive, so that users can tell when your app is active.

Comment: @RaymondChen agreed. For apps which have a unified colour for the title bar n content, might want to consider also dimming the content when the app's not active.